# Perl script to count words and print in one file

Tags: perl, word-count

I’ve been working on a Perl script for my master thesis to extract a small piece of text (CAE) from a 10K (an annual report of a company). I managed to finish writing this script after a lot of work. Now I need to write a new script, but due to a deadline next week, I’m afraid I won’t make it in time to finish. I was wondering if there is someone who can help me with the following problem:

I have almost 52.000 .txt files with a small piece of text. I need a script which writes down the name of each .txt file, and the amount of words and/or characters in this file and copies this of all the files into **one** text file.

Is there someone who could help me please? I would really appreciate it!

This is what I got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $folder;                     #Base directory for the 10K filings
my $subfolder="2012";           #Subdirectory where 10K filings are placed (Default is ./10K/10K_Raw/2012/*.txt)
my $folder10kcae="10K_CAE";     #Name of subdirectory for output (CAE)
my $folderwc="10K_WC";          #Name of subdirectory for output (WordCount)
my $target_cae;                 #Name of target directory for output (CAE)
my $target_wc;                  #Name of target directory for output (WordCount)
my $slash;                      #Declare slash (dependent on operating system)
my $file;                       #Filename
my @allfiles;                   #All files in directory, put into an array
my $allfiles;                   #Total files in directory
my $data;                       #Input file contents
my $cae;                        #Results of the search query (CAE)
my $wc                          #Results of the search query (WordCount)
my $output_cae;                 #Output file with CAE
my $output_wc;                  #Output file with WordCount
my $log;                        #Log file (also used to determine point to continue progress)
my $logfile="$subfolder".".log";#Filename of log file
my @filesinlog;                 #Files that have been processed according to log file

{
#Set folders for Windows. Put raw 10K filings in folder\subfolder
$slash="\\";
$folder="C:\\10KK\\";                    ###specify correct base-map###
}


#Open source folder and read all files
opendir(DIR,"$folder$slash$subfolder") or die $!;
@allfiles=grep /(.\.txt)/, readdir DIR;
chomp(@allfiles);


#Creates destination folder
$target_wc="$folder$slash$folder10kwc$slash$subfolder";

mkdir "$folder$slash$folder10kwc";
mkdir $target_wc;


#Count lines, words and characters
my ($lines, $words, $chars) = (0,0,0);

while ($data=@allfiles) {
$lines++;
$chars += length($_);
$words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $_));
}

open $output_wc, ">", "$target_wc$slash$file" or die $!;
print $output_wc $wc;
close $output_wc;

print("lines=$lines words=$words chars=$chars\n");
```

Comment: If it doesn't *have to* be Perl, wouldn't something like `find . -name '*.txt' -exec wc {} \; > file` do?

Comment: Where do you open the files and read their contents?

Comment: @Biffen No, it doesn't have to be Perl. Could you tell me how to use the 'wc'command? Or direct me to a page where I can learn?

Comment: @WenBo Google would have been a good start, but here you go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you have a bit of a wheel reinvention problem here, and I wouldn't use a perl script. There's a unix command line tool called 'wc' ( short for word count ), that will do everything you want to do with no programming required.

On unix

```
$ wc /path/to/my/folder/* > /path/to/my/output/file.txt
```

On windows, you can download the wc program as part of the  [GNU Coreutils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) package, then run the same command in windows stylee

```
C:\ > wc \path\to\my\folder\* > \path\to\my\output\file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Can this by any chance also be used to count specific words?

Comment: @WenBo You should've mastered google by now.. Why not google first and then ask? #2 result - cat logfile | grep 'word' | wc -l

Comment: @user986959 will your version cope with a word appearing multiple times on one line?